3 Way Lamp That Is Now 1 Way - Can It Be "Cured"?
My lamp WAS a wonderful 3 Way.  Then it became a 1 Way in the last week.  I changed the bulb to a new 3 Way bulb, but no dice.  It still doesn't do 3 Way, only 1 Way.  Is there a way to correct this or is the Lamp just tuckered out and only doing 1 Way now and forever more?  Thanks.

Mechanical things fail. Lamp sockets with integral switches fail. 2-circuit lamp sockets (which use a 3-way bulb) have extra mechanical things that can fail. They are replaceable. Can you post a close-up pic of the inside of the socket, and also a picture of the whole lamp (without shade on)?

Last time I looked, a 3-way lamp switch was $6.  If it takes normal switches, it's an easy swap, your local appliance repairman will be able to take care of you.

It could also be that one of the three contacts in the lamp base needs to be bent up. Unplug the lamp, and use some sort of hook to pry up the two tab contacts a few mm.

Jimmy Fix-It ... I will take a pic.  Thanks.  Yeah it's probably a broken socket.  Later.

Harper -- Thanks.  I'll share a pic first, then hit the hardware store.  I'm totally useless with these things, but worth a shot.

Dr. Moishe ... I'll unplug it after I share a pick here.  See if your idea works.  Thanks!
